# DataViewRowState in a datatable.select

Tags: c#, datatable

Sorry for the simple question, but I'm new to messing with datasets and and things like DataViewRowState. I ran across a line of code that I wasn't really sure what was going on. The line of code is used in a function to save changes from a dataset to the database. Anyhow, in there I saw the following:

```
someDataTable.Select("", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
```

and after poking around online, I found it difficult to find a specific example of this to explain exactly what was being selected here. In particular, I was curious what the difference between that call and

```
someDataTable.Select();
```

might be.

So my question is- what is the difference in results between those two calls?

Comment: AFAIK there is no difference. Dig into `DataTable` class with a reflector to get a solid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Select()` method without parameters is implemented with a call to `Select("","",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)`

This is the output from Reflector

```
public DataRow[] Select()
{
    Bid.Trace("<ds.DataTable.Select|API> %d#\n", this.ObjectID);
    return new Select(this, "", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).SelectRows();
}
```

So there is no difference. 
For the part of your question regarding 'what is selected here' then CurrentRows selects all the rows currently non with the state deleted in the underlying datatable. More info in the [DataViewRowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataviewrowstate.aspx) enum page on MSDN

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you both for your help :)